# populate textbox text in gridview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, gridview, textbox

Could someone help me with the following problem please.
I have a gridview with 2 columns in it. I populate the first column with labels from my datatable with nhibernate criteria. In the second column, i got textboxes. I want to populate them to but i cant get it work. I have this so far:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

foreach (Tabelobject item in list)
                    {
                        DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();

                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.Text = item.objectName;

                        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                        {


                            TextBox txt = row.Cells[0].FindControl("Textbox1") as TextBox;



                             txt.Text = item.objectValue;
                         }
                        NewRow[0] = lbl.Text;

                        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
                    }

                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

in aspx i have to following code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
  <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server">  </asp:TextBox> 
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Im trying to find the textbox control and fill it with the object values. Its not working so far, maybe you guys can help me on my way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable dtCurrentTable = dt; // your datatable
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox tb1= (TextBox)Geidview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("tb1");


                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    tb1.Text = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["tb1"].ToString();


                    rowIndex++;
                }
```

then you bind this `dtCurrentTable` to your gridview

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. what does Grid_AccEntry do? And do i have to make a property of rowindex?